# getting into the loop when the initial condition is false

Tags: c++, recursion

I am confused and have no clue for what is going on here :

```
#include <iostream>

void recur();
int i = 1;

int main() {
  recur();
}

void recur() {
  std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
  while(i++ < 10) {
    recur();
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Here is the output :

```
value of i above while loop : 1

value of i above while loop : 2

value of i above while loop : 3

value of i above while loop : 4

value of i above while loop : 5

value of i above while loop : 6

value of i above while loop : 7

value of i above while loop : 8

value of i above while loop : 9

value of i above while loop : 10
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :11
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :12
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :13
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :14
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :15
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :16
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :17
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :18
statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :19
```

Each time the function `recur` is called it prints its first line and as the value becomes equal to 10 the loop breaks.Now when we are out of the loop how does the statement in the while loop works/prints? Can someone explain what is happening?

**Let me verify**
Am i thinking correctly ? At each call to the function `recur` the control passes back to the beginning of the function definitation . For example:

```
while(i++<10) { 
   recur();
   //...
}
  |
  |
 \ /
void recur() { // here i is 2
    while(i++ < 10) {
        recur();
        //....
    }
} 
  |
  |
 \ /
void recur() { // here i is 3
    while(i++ < 10) {
        recur();
        //....
    }
}
```

Is this the way the calls are going ?

Comment: It return to the place `next line`(not quite right) which the function was called.

Comment: Yes, that's how the calls are going.

Comment: @grassPro: what did you expect the line `recur();` in the `recur()` function to do?  It appears as if you didn't intend the function to be recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when `recur()` returns, you are still in the `while` statement, you have to execute `std::cout` after `recur()`.

```
void recur() {
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    while(i++ < 10) {
        recur();
        // <b>each time `recur()` returns, its return to here</b>
        std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
      }
}
```

ok, I draw a graph

```
while(i++<10) { 
    recur();
    //...       <---------return to here--
}                                        |
                                         |
void recur() { // here i is 2            |
    while(i++ < 10) {                    |
        recur();                         |
        //....  <-----return to here---- |
    }                                  | |
    return; ------------------------------
}                                      |
                                       |
void recur() { // here i is 3          |
    while(i++ < 10) {                  |
        recur();                       |
        //....                         |
    }                                  |
    return; ----------------------------
}
```

Comment: ok . After the last recur returns and prints the statement just after the call to recur, then how does the remaining statements get printed ?

Comment: Does the last means the 11 time `recur()` was called, it will not execute the second `std::cout`

Comment: if it returns just after the `recur` then how the value of i is incremented to beyond 10 as the while loop won't evaluate.

Comment: @grassPro No, the `while` will always execute, the statements in it block won't execute.

Comment: you seem to contradict your own statement. you said that the function returns after the call to `recur` . So during unfolding if the statement next to `recur` executes how will the value of i increment

Comment: @grassPro I mean when i = 10(which was the last time you call recur), the `while(i++ < 10)` turn i to 11, then returns.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4077/discussion-between-lostyzd-and-grasspro)

Answer (score 3):

The variable i continues to increment because the while conditional must be executed one more time to make sure it is false, causing i to increment even though it is over 10 for each call to recur().

If you placed the incrementation of i outside of the conditional, the results would be more in line with what you are expecting.  For example:

```
while (i < 10) {
    i++;
    // Do rest.
}
```

But with your code as it currently is, each time the conditional is tested, i continues to be incremented, even though the conditional is false.

Comment: I have updated my answer to more thoroughly explain why i continues to increment past 10.  Yes, you are absolutely correct in how the program is executing.

Comment: the thing that is unclear to me is how come the program control is still on while loop after the recursive calls are over and the folding is being done. Because when the program is getting back after the recursive calls are over, it will execute the statements just after the statement `recur`. How the program still lingers over while loop and if it does the recursion will never get over !

Comment: The recur function is entered 10 times.  The last recur call executes the while condition one more time to make sure that it is false (which increments i to 11), causing the recur call to exit.  The next recur then does the same thing, then the next until all recur calls have exited.  This is why i gets incremented to 19.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing recursion and iteration in a rather strange way.

The first recur() calls a second one, which calls a third one and so on. Each increments i. When the tenth nested function call increments i to 10 it returns. The 9th function call then prints the message, increments i once more, exits the loop and returns to the 8th which does the same.

None of the functions go round the while loop more than once - because when the nested recur() call returns i is always at least 10.

Why would you do this?

Comment: +1 for "Why would you do this?"  This smells like a contrived homework question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the flow of your program:

```
value   function    stack depth
-----   --------    -----------
i = 1   recur()     0
i = 1   print i     1
i = 1   i++         1
i = 2   recur()     1
i = 2   print i     2
i = 2   i++         2
i = 3   recur()     2
i = 3   print i     3
i = 3   i++         3
i = 4   recur()     3
i = 4   print i     4
i = 4   i++         4
i = 5   recur()     4
i = 5   print i     5
i = 5   i++         5
i = 6   recur()     5
i = 6   print i     6
i = 6   i++         6
i = 7   recur()     6
i = 7   print i     7
i = 7   i++         7
i = 8   recur()     7
i = 8   print i     8
i = 8   i++         8
i = 9   recur()     8
i = 9   print i     9
i = 9   i++         9
i = 10  recur()     9
i = 10  print i     10
i = 10  i++         10
i = 11  return      10
i = 11  print i     9
i = 11  i++         9
i = 12  return      9
i = 12  print i     8
i = 12  i++         8
i = 13  return      8
i = 13  print i     7
i = 13  i++         7
i = 14  return      7
i = 14  print i     6
i = 14  i++         6
i = 15  return      6
i = 15  print i     5
i = 15  i++         5
i = 16  return      5
i = 16  print i     4
i = 16  i++         4
i = 17  return      4
i = 17  print i     3
i = 17  i++         3
i = 18  return      3
i = 18  print i     2
i = 18  i++         2
i = 19  return      2
i = 19  print i     1
i = 19  i++         1
i = 20  return      1
i = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

After the condition becomes false in the innermost call to recur, it breaks out of the loop and returns correctly.  It returns to the second-innermost-call to recur, which displays the value of `i`, and then goes back to the beginning of the while loop to check the condition again.  The condition is `(i++ < 10)`, so it increments `i` a second time (to eleven now), sees that it's greater than ten, and returns to the third-innermost-call.  The third innermost increments checks `(i++ < 10)` requiring it to increment `i` (to twelve) before it knows to break out of *it's* loop.  etc.

Basically, you have one loop per call.  It only breaks out of one at a time.  You want:

```
void recur() {
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //here, outside the loop
    while(i < 10) {
        recur();
        std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
Yes, when a function calls itself, the computer will call that function again, and when the inner function returns, it will return to exactly where it was in the outer function.  Basically, just like any other function call works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to explain it is to show how I'd rewrite the function to be more readable. Each of the following snippets will have output identical to your original code (provided that i == 1 when recur() is first called)

First, let's take the postincrement operator out of the conditional, because I think it's confusing. This code is equivalent:

```
void recur() {
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    while(i < 10){
        i++;
        recur();
        std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;

    }
    i++;
}
```

Note how there is an i++ at the end. This is because in the original code, i will increment itself in the (i++ < 10) condition, even when the conditional doesn't evaluate to true and doesn't enter the loop.

Next, you can sort of "unroll" recur by repeatedly inlining the code. I'm also tracking the value of i each time its value changes.

```
void recur() {
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    while(i < 10){
        i++; //i == 2
        std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
        while(i < 10){
            i++; //i == 3
            std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
            while(i < 10){
                i++; //i ==4
                std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
                while(i < 10){
                    i++; //i == 5
                    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
                    while(i < 10){
                        i++; //i == 6
                        std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
                        while(i < 10){
                            i++; //i == 7
                            std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
                            while(i < 10){
                                i++; //i == 8
                                std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
                                while(i < 10){
                                    i++; //i == 9
                                    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
                                    while(i < 10){
                                        i++; //i == 10
                                        std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
                                        while(i < 10){//this doesn't evaluate to true since i == 10
                                            //we stop unrolling here because the interior of this loop won't be executed anyway
                                        }
                                        i++; // i == 11
                                        std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
                                    }
                                    i++;
                                    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
                                }
                                i++;
                                std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
                            }
                            i++;
                            std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
                        }
                        i++;
                        std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
                    }
                    i++;
                    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
                }
                i++;
                std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
            }
            i++;
            std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
        }
        i++;
        std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Note how each while loop only executes exactly once - by the time any single while loop finishes for the first time, i is greater than ten, so no loop will be entered a second time. With this in mind, we can get rid of the whiles entirely, and save ourselves some indentation.

```
void recur() {
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 2
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 3
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i ==4
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 5
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 6
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 7
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 8
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 9
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; //i == 10
    std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
    i++; // i == 11
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
    i++;
}
```

May as well optimize some of these repetitive statements...

```
void recur(){
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        std::cout << "\nvalue of i above while loop : " << i << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
        std::cout << "statement just after the recursive call to tester and here the value of i is :" << i << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now it is fairly obvious to see that the first statement prints itself for i = 1 to 10, and the second from i = 11 to 19.